# how to use input type="file" event handler in chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, input, google-chrome-app

I want to be able to open files through **input type="file"** in chrome apps.
The following code produce an error:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" onchange="btnClick(event)" />

    <script>
        function btnClick(evt) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                var str = event.target.result;
                console.log(str);
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline event handlers dont work in chrome apps, remove event handler from the html and implement it in javascript. Also, the script must not be in the html file. it should be in its own js file and referenced in the html. This is documented [HERE](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

html

```
<input type="file" id="file1"/>
```

js

```
document.getElementById("file1").addEventListener("change",handleChange);

function handleChange(){
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            var str = event.target.result;
            console.log(str);
        }
    fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);    
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sionnach733/2MTN9/)